# Have I discovered a solution to updating a signal in a loop in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm a computer engineering student and we have started to get out feet wet with hardware design using VHDL. I'm getting a better understanding of how the process clock works in VHDL. To my best understanding, in the process sensitivity with regards to the clock, VHDL will look for when the clock is either rising or falling, and the entire process will complete only in that instance. So I, by chance, after many failed attempts tried the code below, and it worked! In the for loop my input(D) will load 8 different values/vectors into RAM when load is high and will send those RAM values to the output(Q) when the load is low. But how is this possible?

I assumed, given my past failure in getting this to work that when the clock is rising there is only one value/vector for the input(D) and only one value/vector for the output(Q). How are there 8 different values/vectors of D and Q getting passed to RAM and passed from RAM? Does the (address) signal iterate in the loop separately from the clock, but even if that were the case, how would it know what the next 7 values/vectors of the input(D) will be?

[Timing diagram for the code, simulates the process correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7UTG.png)

Here is the VHDL code

```
Library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
ENTITY RAM_8Register IS
    PORT(D           : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
         load, clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
         address     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0);
         Q           : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0));
END RAM_8Register;
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF RAM_8Register IS
TYPE Array8x16 IS ARRAY(7 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL RAM : Array8x16;
SIGNAL index : INTEGER RANGE 0 to 7;
BEGIN
PROCESS (clock)
BEGIN
IF (rising_edge(clock)) THEN
    IF (load='1') THEN
        FOR i IN index'RANGE LOOP
            RAM(TO_INTEGER((UNSIGNED(address))))<=D;
        END LOOP;
        Q<=D;
    ELSE
        FOR i IN index'RANGE LOOP
            Q<=RAM(TO_INTEGER((UNSIGNED(address))));
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END IF;
END PROCESS;
END Behavior;
```

Comment: *But how is this possible?* First signal updates are scheduled in a projected output waveform (queue) that is sparse (only scheduled events) with only one entry for a particular simulation time (assignment defaults to the current time, there are simulation cycles that don't advance sim time). Your loops assign the same values 8 times, only the last remains queued when the process suspends. The Q <= D; assignment in the if statement is responsible for the Q values. Your simulator may be capable of displaying RAM contents which would demonstrate clock edge updates to specific addresses.

Comment: While the for loop's aren't necessary here the signal assignments contained within them are. If you had provided a [mcve] here including a testbench a reader here could demonstrate that each clock rising edge with load = '1' only one value is written to one address.

Comment: The predefined attribute 'RANGE prefix is required to be an array object or a constrained array subtype, while index (index'RANGE) is an integer object. Your code isn't valid. RAM'RANGE is valid and has the same range. (Noted previously the loops aren't needed.)

Comment: As VHDL is a **descrption** language, such a `FOR` loop describes as many statements as defined, here `index'RANGE`. However, since you don't use `i` in the loop body, you simply create 8 equal statements. Try the same source without the loop. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] including the testbench.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a testbench. Would that be different than the code I provided? My main confusion is when load ='0' this is when RAM is sent the output. In the timing diagram I posted in the question at the 90ns mark RAM[1] is outputted, but to my understanding in the first loop only RAM[7] is saved and it gets overwritten in the next clock cycle, but all the array elements have different values viewed in the waveform diagram. I'm aware the loop is not needed, I thought the loop would cause an incorrect output. @user16145658

Comment: I did get the same results without a loop, but I was under the assumption that including a loop would cause incorrect outputs when load='0'. I apologize but I'm not familiar with a testbench. Is that not the same as my VHDL code? @thebusybee

Comment: After thinking about it a little more I think I understand what's happening now. Because I'm using the (address) signal to move along the array, that address stays the same in the loop during each clock cycle. So when the address is 3, D will get sent to RAM[3] 7 times and gets stored. This repeats until the RAM array is filled. Thank you @user16145658

Comment: No, this is not true: "_D will get sent to RAM[3] 7 times_". You do not "program", you "describe" a hardware. It is "_Please provide 8 times the selection wire #3 of the 1-out-of-8 decoder to write to RAM[3]_". Apparently you come from a software programming background, but VHDL does not work this way. Processes are not "run" but describe combinatorial or sequential (clocked) logic. A hard to grasp difference is the semantic of simulation-only statements. Please obtain a good introduction to VHDL before wrong models build up in your mind.

Comment: In the course, do some research on test benches. Your code does not include a test bench. What generated the timing diagram, who specified the addresses, data and clock? There has to be some test driver for the instantiated component of your architecture. Look at it like this: The "entity" defines the pinning of a component like an IC, and the "architecture" describes one possible inner logic. But this alone cannot produce the timing diagram, therefore you need a test bench.

Comment: I understand that VHDL is a descriptive language of hardware. I'm not sure where you're getting the notion that I don't understand that. The exact terminology I'm using is getting into semantics. When I say D is sent to RAM, I understand that it's describing wires, signals, circuit, etc. I just assumed that was already known between us and there would be no need to directly mention it. About the testbench, that hasn't been mentioned in my class, not yet at least, but I'll look deeper into it, it seems important so I'll like to know more about it. @thebusybee

Comment: These waveforms compare [with and without the for loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlkdK.jpg) while retaining the assignments to Q and addressed RAM. Also note that writes are sequential, one for each D value  during a clock with load = '1' and a particular address.

Comment: You can simulate any VHDL description as long as it is syntactically and grammatically correct (translating it to hardware is a completely different matter). Your description is correct, so it simulates. During the simulation on each rising edge of `clock` if `load='1'` you assign `D` to `RAM(TO_INTEGER((UNSIGNED(address))))` 8 times in the same simulation step. Only the last assignment has an effect. You could as well remove your loop. Same when `load='0'`, you assign `RAM(TO_INTEGER((UNSIGNED(address))))` to `Q` 8 times and only the last one matters.

Answer (score 0):

VHDL is a **hardware description language**, not a **programming language**. Therefore, there is no sequence like you write "*iterat[ion] in the loop separately from the clock*". On each rising clock edge, exactly one RAM word is written or stored in the output register.

This is a (probably overly simplified or even partly erroneous) possible implementation of your logic:

[image: possible implementation]

The marked areas show the result of your loops, red for the first loop writing into the RAM, and green for the second loop reading from the RAM. Actually, I multiplied only the signals for `address` = 0. For the other addresses, there are also multiple signals.

However, the synthesizer will optimize all these duplicates away. So your loops make no sense. At least they are harmless.

Oh, and for clarity I omitted the assignment `Q <= D;` on writing to the RAM.

So you can simplify your design to the following:

```vhdl
Library ieee;

USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY RAM_8Register IS
    PORT(D           : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
         load, clock : IN STD_LOGIC;
         address     : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0);
         Q           : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0));
END RAM_8Register;

ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF RAM_8Register IS
    TYPE Array8x16 IS ARRAY(7 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);

    SIGNAL RAM : Array8x16;
    SIGNAL index : INTEGER RANGE 0 to 7;
BEGIN
    PROCESS (clock)
    BEGIN
        IF (rising_edge(clock)) THEN
            IF (load='1') THEN
                RAM(TO_INTEGER((UNSIGNED(address))))<=D;
                Q<=D;
            ELSE
                Q<=RAM(TO_INTEGER((UNSIGNED(address))));
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END Behavior;
```

Your confusion comes from the part that is missing from the provided source, as we discussed in the comments: **the test bench**. There has to be some logic that generated the clock, data, addresses, and load signal you show us in your timing diagram. That test bench drives the RAM.

The test bench (not presented in the question) generates the clock signal, applies the different values to `D` and `address`, and switches `load`.

There is no magic in the loops. Your doubts apparent in "*how would it know what the next 6 values/vectors of the input(D) will be?*" point in the right direction. You just missed to take the next step.

The following is untested and only a part of such a test bench.

```vhdl
entity TB is
end entity;

architecture Test of TB is
    component RAM_8Register is
        port(D           : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
             load, clock : in std_logic;
             address     : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
             Q           : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    signal clock:   std_logic;
    signal load:    std_logic;
    signal address: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    signal D:       std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal Q:       std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
begin
    architecture_under_test: entity work.RAM_8Register(Behavior)
        port map (D, load, clock, address, Q);

    write1: process
    begin
        clock <= '0';
        load <= '1';
        address <= "000";
        D <= x"1234";

        wait for 5 ns;
        clock <= '1';

        wait for 5 ns;
        clock <= '0';
        address <= "001";
        D <= x"1235";

        -- and so on ...
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Please note that a test bench is commonly only simulated. Therefore, it can use non-synthesizable statement like `wait for 5 ns;`. But such statements cannot be synthesized into real hardware.

Comment: I understand the comments are not meant to just say thank you, but I have to tell you how much I appreciate the effort and time you've taken to give me such a detailed and informative answer.  You have given me a better understanding of the topic, and I hope to become as good as you are in my career. Again, thank you.

Comment: _"But such statements cannot be synthesized into real hardware."_ well, one _could_ write a synthesizer that would parse that.  E.g. implementing a timer or so. But it's good nobody does that, as it would cause much confusion and inefficient circuits.

Comment: @JHBonarius Sure, there is no such synthesizer. Some "clever" users will try to actually delay for 5 ns. Or 1 s. What kind of real FPGA will be able to realize that? What manufacturer will dare to provide the necessary user service? -- However, after synthesizing, most tool chains are able to produce a VHDL representation of the implemented logic. And this code includes `after x ps` clauses that are parameterized for the different possible operation conditions like supply voltage and temperature. This is the only place a delay makes sense in a real device.

Comment: I disagree that VHDL is _not a programming language_. I think it is and you don't have to limit its use to hardware modelling and synthesis. I wrote a lot of VHDL that was not modeling hardware, just because of its intrinsic parallel nature. Moreover, many simulation environments are not modeling hardware, reason why they freely use pointers, dynamic memory allocation, files and the VHPI procedural interface. If you design a simulation environment that checks the functional correctness of a design, parts of it are just algorithms, coded almost as they would be in any programming language.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, you can _program_ simulations in VHDL. I did this, too, of course.  If you want automated unit tests, you need to. And what is a program else than a description of an algorithm? -- However, it is in its name: Very High Speed Integrated Circuit Hardware **Description** Language. And by far the most problems of beginners stem from the interpretation as a programming language, especially here. So I'm being kind of dogmatic here. -- You can also use programming languages for descriptions. The border is blurry.

Comment: @thebusybee I understand your point but still, I disagree. One of the main issues for beginners is to not make a clear difference between simulation and synthesis, to not understand that the semantics are totally different... This is a simulation question and I think it deserves explanations about the simulation semantics (what the LRM says). Whether it could be synthesized and with what results is a different topic. I think too many VHDL coders limit themselves to a ridiculous subset of what VHDL offers because they have been polluted with this _synthesis or death_ bias.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet It is OK to have different points of view, and I accept your disagreement. -- The problem with the OP's question is that the `for` loop does not what it would as a programming construct, as the question shows. But it does what a describing construct does. -- Anyway, I'm afraid this discussion is fruitless, as long as the OP does not comment. ;-)